# When scrolling the Browser screen content does not move when using bootstrap

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have fixed header and a bootstrap menu but when i scroll the browser screen nothing happens.
Please give some suggestions. Is there any css problem or a conflict because when i remove bootstrap dropdown menu it starts working.

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
      <div class="container">
      </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your content is inside the navigation which you've set to be fixed (`navbar-fixed-top`). Put the content outside the navbar.

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
</div>

<div class="container">
</div>
```

If you're concerned that the fixed navbar covers a part of the container, add some top margin or padding to the container.